# Dart Future: when throwing Error, the the main thread is interrupted, but in Flutter it's not

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous, future

I tried to test the behavior of future, but

Throwing an exception in future will break the dart main thread

However, the reverse is true in the Flutter:

Dart Code

```
   Future(() async {
                    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 10));
                    print("TimeOut");
                  }).timeout(Duration(seconds: 5));

                  Future(() async {
                    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 15));
                    print("AAAAAAA");
                  });
```

in Dart use the code  `dart run ./a.dart`

```
Unhandled exception:
TimeoutException after 0:00:05.000000: Future not completed
```

in Flutter:

```
E/flutter (11789): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: TimeoutException after 0:00:05.000000: Future not completed
E/flutter (11789):
I/flutter (11789): TimeOut
I/flutter (11789): AAAAAAA
```

Why ?

Comment: That's interesting and seems to be the same behaviour as my library, structured_async, in Flutter! The reason I chose this design in structured_async is that leaving a Future's synchronous code hanging and never completing in cases like this could cause important work to  never run... by waking up the code when an error occurs, the code will actually "observe" an error when it tries to get something async, which prevents hanging forever in some situations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between Dart and Flutter is that Flutter catches all unhandled exceptions and just prints them out (including the stack trace). This is on purpose and the secret is that Flutter registers a callback to the static class function [FlutterError.onError](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/FlutterError/onError.html) and the default implementation is the function [FlutterError.presentError](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/FlutterError/presentError.html). Some more details on the official docs: [Handling errors in Flutter](https://docs.flutter.dev/testing/errors)

---

### Disable terminating on fatal errors in Dart

It's possible to disable terminating the app/script on fatal errors by calling [Isolate.setErrorsFatal](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.0.0/dart-isolate/Isolate/setErrorsFatal.html) with `false`. For example, to keep async code running even if an unhandled exception is thrown just do this.

```dart
void main () {
  Isolate.current.setErrorsFatal(false); // <- Here

  Future(() async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 10));
    print("TimeOut");
  }).timeout(Duration(seconds: 5));

  Future(() async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 15));
    print("AAAAAAA");
  });
}
```

And the output is going to be:

```
TimeOut
AAAAAAA
```

---

### Dart with the same behaviour as Flutter

The following code simulates the same thing Flutter does in Dart with [runZonedGuarded](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.3/dart-async/runZonedGuarded.html):

```dart
import 'dart:async';

void main(List<String> args) {
  runZonedGuarded(program, errorHandler);
}

void program() {
  Future(() async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 10));
    print("TimeOut");
  }).timeout(Duration(seconds: 5));

  Future(() async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 15));
    print("AAAAAAA");
  });
}

void errorHandler(Object error, StackTrace stack) {
  print('Unhandled exception:\n$error');
}
```

The output is going to be the following in Dart:

```
Unhandled exception:
TimeoutException after 0:00:05.000000: Future not completed
TimeOut
AAAAAAA
```

---

### Flutter with the same behaviour as Dart

On the other hand, it's possible to do the same thing in Flutter as Dart does. I.e. kills the app on whenever unhandled exception. It's just a matter of using the [runZonedGuarded](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.3/dart-async/runZonedGuarded.html) again:

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runZonedGuarded(() async {
    runApp(const MyApp());
  }, (Object error, StackTrace stack) {
    print('Unhandled exception:\n$error');
    exit(1);
  });
}

void program() {
  Future(() async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 10));
    print("TimeOut");
  }).timeout(Duration(seconds: 5));

  Future(() async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 15));
    print("AAAAAAA");
  });
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    program();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      builder: (context, child) => const Scaffold(
        body: Center(child: Text('The app is going to exit in 5 seconds...')),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The output is going to be the following:

```
flutter: Unhandled exception:
TimeoutException after 0:00:05.000000: Future not completed
Lost connection to device.
```